# Adding multiple views to a Fragment using a LayoutInflater

Tags: android

I am trying to put some views into a Fragment using a LayoutInflater. They are TextViews, but I only seem to be able to set the values on the first ones I add. It looks like an id clash is causing the problem, but I am at a loss as to how to get over this. 
The relevant bit of my onCreateView looks like this:

```
    ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.data_viewer,
            container, false);

    HashMap<String, Long> titles = mHelper.getTitles("firestations");

    for (String key : titles.keySet()) {
        **View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, vg, true);
        TextView label = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        label.setText(key);**
        TextView value = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        value.setText(getArg(key));
    }
```

As you can see from the starred lines I am inflating a 'row' (this is just a horizontal linear layout with 2 text views called textView1 and textView2 in it). I supply the handle of the ViewGroup that I inflated and pass true to get the views attached to the parent. All of this seems to work fine. Then I call findViewById on the row that I have just inflated. I would have thought that this find would only pick up the children of that specific row. It looks like the find is using a wider scope and is matching the full set of ids (which are the same - they are all from the same piece of xml). It is then giving me back the first one. 
The result of all this is that I am getting the screen correctly laid out with the last row of data displayed on the top pair of TextViews. The rest of the TextViews have their xml defined default text in them.

Anyone know how I can get around this?

Thanks,

Anthony Nolan

Comment: Try using `false` for the third parameter of your `inflate()` call in the loop, then adding the row to the `ViewGroup` manually after configuring it. In principle, what you have looks good, so I'm just taking a guess here. Also, please use the `commonsware` tag for things that pertain to my books or open source projects -- this question pertains to neither.

Comment: I tried this before I got your suggestion and it works. Looks like a little bug, but now that I know its there and I can get around it, no bother. Fair comment on the tags. I though it just meant 'can you have a look at this'! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there might be a minor bug in the support code. Adding the views explicitly (instead of using the true param) works fine:

```
    for (String key : titles.keySet()) {
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, vg, false);
        TextView label = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        label.setText(key);
        TextView value = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        value.setText(getArg(key));
        vg.addView(row);
    }
```